# How to get IDFA and ADID on react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I want to get the ADID on Android, and IDFA on IOS, how to do this on react native ?
i use this library called **react-native-idfa** , but the library always said undefined on IDFA

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same problem.  Make sure your iAd.framework is linked the Xcode -> "Build Phases":

[image]

They do mention this on their github https://github.com/FreebirdRides/react-native-idfa#podfile

Add AdSupport.framework under "Link Binary With Libraries":

[image]

We forked the react-native-idfa if you want to use ours:

https://github.com/FreebirdRides/react-native-idfa

This commit in particular:

https://github.com/FreebirdRides/react-native-idfa/commit/9c6992a53dd109bed41e8c8300906a71e6068043